# Getting NoMethodError in Statuses#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm building a social media website with Ruby on Rails and i'm following instructions from teamtreehouse.com . Every time i make a new status or go to the index page i get this message

```
undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass

  <p>
    <strong>Name:</strong>
    <%= @status.user.full_name %>
  </p>
```

I coded my pages to show the full name with this

```
<%= @status.user.full_name %>
```

and

```
<%= status.user.full_name %>
```

for the index page.

I have included all of these snippets of code into my project as well

**status.rb**

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :content, :user_id
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
                  :first_name, :last_name, :profile_name
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  def full_name 
    first_name + " " + last_name
  end
end
```

I've tried using `rake db:reset` and `rake db:migrate` but nothing seems to solve the error problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Make sure that the status object you are looking at has an associated user. Looks like it doesn't. Check in rails console, if the particular status record has user_id= nil

Answer (score 1):

As per the error,

```
undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass
```

which means that

```
@status.user = nil
```

i.e., the particular status instance that you are looking at(`@status`) doesn't have an associated user record.

You can verify it by going to `rails console`

```
Status.find(pass_the_id)   ## pass the id of @status instance
```

You will notice that `user_id` is `nil` for that record.

Set the value to an existing `user_id` and try again.

***Note:*** you might need to take a deeper look at how you are storing a status in your application. I suppose you are missing to store `user_id` attribute there

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'd need to include `has_many :statuses` in the `User` model

You may also wish to use the [`.delegate()`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method:

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :content, :user_id

    belongs_to :user
    delegate :full_name, to :user, prefix: :author
end
```

This should allow you to call `@status.author_full_name`

Comment: Just added that in but still getting the same error message

Comment: Show us your schema. Does it raise the error if you call an actual attribute (`first_name`) etc?